# How to add custom zoom controls to the map built using angular-google-maps

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, angular-google-maps

I am currently using angular-google-maps and have built a working map displaying a few markers from the backend. What I wish to do is to add custom zoom controls to the map. Hence I did this. But it is not working as expected. If anybody has worked on it before or knows how, then can you please help me out?

This is my directive-view:

```
 %ui-gmap-google-map(center='map.center' pan='map.pan' options='map.options' draggable='true' zoom='map.zoom')
  %ui-gmap-marker(ng-repeat='marker in map.markers' idKey="marker.id" coords='marker.coords' location='marker.location' icon="marker.icon" click="marker.click")
     %ui-gmap-window(show="marker.showWindow" isIconVisibleOnClick="marker.isIconVisibleOnClick" options="map.infoWindowCustomClass.options")
        .tooltip-container
          %p.paragraph-one {{marker.appName}}
          %ul
            %li {{marker.city}}, {{marker.country}}
            %li Users: {{marker.userName}}
.mapzoomControls
   %i.fa.fa-minus-square.zoom-icons(ng-click='increaseMapZoom()')
   %i.fa.fa-plus-square.zoom-icons(ng-click='decreaseMapZoom()')
```

Here is my directive:

```
'use strict'

 angular.module('protoV3App')
 .directive('dashboardMap',[ 'mapSettings',(mapSettings) ->
  templateUrl: 'views/dashboardmap.html'
  restrict: 'E'
  link: (scope, element, attrs) ->
    scope.increaseMapZoom = ()->
        mapSettings.increaseMapZoom()
        scope.$apply()
    scope.decreaseMapZoom = ()->
        mapSettings.decreaseMapZoom()
        scope.$apply()


   ])
```

The corresponding functions in the service:

```
increaseMapZoom: ()-> 
    currentMap.zoom =currentMap.zoom+1;
    currentMap;
decreaseMapZoom: ()-> 
    currentMap.zoom =currentMap.zoom-1;
    currentMap;
```

So the error I get is that apply is already in progress and the changed map object is not reflected in the scope. :(

Answer (score 0):

The reason because you are getting this error because you are calling $apply inside an existing digestion cycle.

To get rid of this issue add these lines in your code:

```
if ($scope.$root.$$phase != '$apply' && $scope.$root.$$phase != '$digest') {
    $scope.$apply();
}
```